# Page is getting flickered while switching between bootstrap tabs

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core-mvc

I have made a partial view of tabs and clicking on it respective page/view will get rendered and rendered this partial view in each view. Below is my tabs partial view

```
<div id="divClass">
    <ul id="classTab" class="nav nav-tabs bordered">
        <li class="active" id="Classlistli">
            <a href="@Url.Action("ClassList", "Class")" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-list"></i>Class List</a>
        </li>
        <li id="Classdetails">
            <a href="@Url.Action("ClassDetails", "Class")" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-file"></i>Class Details</a>
        </li>
        <li id="ClassSchedule">
            <a href="@Url.Action("ClassSchedule", "Class")" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-calendar "></i>Class Schedule</a>
        </li>
        <li id="ClassQnA">
            <a href="@Url.Action("ClassQnA", "Class")" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-comments-o"></i>Class QnA</a>
        </li>
        <li id="instApprove">
            <a href="@Url.Action("InstructorReview", "Class")" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-star-half-o"></i>Instructor Review</a>
        </li>
        <li id="classTrainne">
            <a href="@Url.Action("ClassTrainee", "Class")" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-users"></i> Class Trainee</a>
        </li>
       </ul>
</div>
```

Below is screenshot how my tabs looks
[image]

Below is the screenshot which is occurred while switching between the tabs
[image]

and after this selected tab is rendered/displayed properly, Like this
[image]

My issue is whenever I am switching between tabs, for some time the entire page getting blank,white and then the respective tab is rendered.

Let's say I am switching the tab from '**Class Details**' to '**Class Schedule**', I have written following in controller

```
Public ActionResult ClassSchedule()
{
  Return View();
}
```

and in ClassSchedule view, I have rendered the Tabs partial view like this,

```
<div id='divResult'>
  @{
      Html.RenderPartial("~/ViewsBackend/class/_classtab.cshtml");
   }
</div>
<div>
// my class schedule view and its content
</div>
```

I have also set the active tab from javascript function, which is included in all views. Also, we want the separate url on each tab load, that's why we are not using the AJAX call.

So, how can I solve/stop the page flickering while switching the tabs ?

Comment: I know absolutely nothing about asp.net. Does your code make an HTTP request for the HTML tab content when you click the tab?

Comment: @bassxzero Yes, thats what Url.Action do, it gets the data from controller(server side) and sends back to the page

Comment: Then it just sounds the flicker is from the time it takes the browser to fetch the data then add it to the DOM and render it. To verify you can fetch the tab content at page load instead of when the tab is clicked.

Comment: I am doing the same, tabs are in different page and the tab content is a different page. So on click of tab the page url is getting called and returns the data

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying the problem is. Events: click tab -> show blank/white tab content -> send Ajax HTTP request to server for content -> wait for server to return content -> receive tab content -> insert tab content into DOM -> browser render refresh which shows tab content. If this event log is correct then the flicker is coming from the delay between displaying the blank tab and the render refresh of the tab.

Comment: Yes, the sequence of events is right. Only the thing is I am not making the ajax request,  instead posting the entire page. The issue might be that I have added the tabs page reference in each tab content page, so while rendering the respective tab content page, each time new tabs page reference is getting added.  And, talking about data, its very less, almost 100 records

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138834/discussion-between-bassxzero-and-rohit).